# ActionView::Template::Error (highcharts.js isn't precompiled)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Hi again I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku but I got this error:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

I don't know why happens this, I already precompiled the assets with

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

if you want to see my logs its here:

```
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 190.242.128.66 at 2012-08-13 16:03:42 +0000
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 87ms
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (highcharts.js isn't precompiled):
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"  %>
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts" %>
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:     9: 
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: </head>
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___263981703336480791_52466080'
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 app[web.1]: 
            2012-08-13T16:03:42+00:00 heroku[router]: GET boiling-bastion-5936.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=326ms status=500 bytes=643
            2012-08-13T16:03:43+00:00 heroku[router]: GET boiling-bastion-5936.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=0
```

here's my application on [github](https://github.com/asantoya/tankinlog) for you to review
  on github

Comment: Why are you including highcharts separately? Your `require_tree .` statement here: https://github.com/asantoya/tankinlog/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js will include all the JS files

Comment: already I have resolved but now I'm to curiosity, how do  I add the js files in this file

Comment: You'll want to specify different JS files individually, remove the `require_tree .` line, and explicitly list the files you want to include in your `application.js`. After that, you can include files you did not include separately, and those will have to be listed in the production.rb file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uncomment [this line](https://github.com/asantoya/tankinlog/blob/master/config/environments/production.rb#L49). That should include the asset during precompilation

I noticed that you are actually using require tree in [your application.js](https://github.com/asantoya/tankinlog/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js), at which point, including it separately becomes redundant and is probably what is causing the issue.